When does "Date modified" change for files in Windows Explorer as I want to use it in Powershell?
I'd like to understand the behaviour of the "Date modified" in Windows Explorer. There is a process which syncs folders with csv files beetween a data provider and a network share. I'm wondering if the "Date modified" shows the actual delivery timestamp if no manual update happens.
If I also show the column date created it sometimes is a lot of days later.
Example "Date modified" = 03.12.2024 hh:mm and "Date created" = 13.12.2024
Which suggested to me that maybe "Date modified" is set when the file is either published (or updated) by the data vendor or when it's put on the share. While "Date created" gets updated every time as the sync just does a bulk delivery also for some days back.
"Date modified" = "Date" = "Content created" = "Date last saved"
"Date created" = "Date accessed"
Thanks!

Check out this excellent video on MACb timestamps in Windows. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTea54BelTg If you'd rather not a yt video, here is a good reference on MACb as well: https://andreafortuna.org/2017/10/06/macb-times-in-windows-forensic-analysis/

This question belongs on [su], as it is a general OS question. SO is strictly for questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). You can find more information about what is appropriate to ask about here in the [help].

@KenWhite okay I see. Then maybe let me rephrase: "How does "Date modified" work in general (and not only folders) so I can analyse some files via Powershell. ;)

Adding the word "Powershell" does not change it magically from an OS question into a programming question, any more than adding the word steak after the word turd makes it an appetizing meal. :-) It's 'not a programming question, and belongs on [su].
